Is this a good explanation of Aristotle's Wheel Paradox?
I propose an easy explanation of the classic Aristotle wheel paradox.
In the paradox a large wheel for example: 10in diameter with 2 points one (point a) on the edge, at position x:0 and y:0 and the second (point b), recessed 4inches from the edge at x:0 y:4, start at the 6 o'clock position. The wheel is rolled without slipage and after 1 revolution both points are again at the 6 o'clock position. The apparent paradox lies in the appearance of both point spinning in different sized orbits while appearing to have traveled the same distance.
The explanation I propose, is to liken the issue to a passenger car with a transmission. I'f you drive a car in 1st gear and maintain 1000rpms on the engine the car will travel 20mph and the engine will complete 60,000 revolutions in 1 hour while traveling 20 miles. Now, if you repeat the same conditions but do it in 5th gear you will travel 60mph and the engine will still complete 60,000 revolutions in 1 hour except you will have driven 60 miles. The wheel of the paradox is the crankshaft of the engine. The outer (point b) is 5th gear and the inner (point a) is 1st gear.
My question is, is this a good explanation and or a good metaphor for what is demonstrated in the paradox?

What is a crankshaft?
